# Devs, can 3rd party apps access Safari's Reading List?

Tags: ios, cocoa, reading-list

Any chance iOS 5 lets devs access Reading List in Safari? A potential Read Later option for Twitter clients, etc.

I've been asking devs through Twitter for a while, but am yet to hear anything back.

Comment: "The verge" app does it. Have no idea how..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't think there is official support for third-party access to the reading list from Apple, but I know they are stored in this file on the Mac, and I would assume it is the same on iOS, or close to:

> ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist

Just look for a key that has an entry named "Title" and a key value of "com.apple.ReadingList". It's the last one in my own file, but I don't expect it to be like this all the way.

And I suggest looking at it with a property list editor, like Xcode 4, it's a binary property list, doesn't look right when opened in TextEdit or other similar app.

Comment: Assuming the file is the same on iOS (which it very well might be), there will be no way to access it, as it is sandboxed – meaning only Safari itself can read it.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Forgot about sandboxing on iOS... Well, unless there is a dedicated API or method, I don't see how it would be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys! I guess what I was looking for was evidence of an Reading List API. Doesn't look promising tho… Too bad!