# How to get Reading List items as links

Tags: macos, icloud, safari, reading-list

I just have a billion items in Safari's reading list and I would like the links to all of them.

Is there a way to get all of the items in your reading list as links (maybe in a text document)?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30519/devs-can-3rd-party-apps-access-safaris-reading-list

Comment: Is the 'reading list' plist file the same as the 'bookmarks' plist file?

Comment: The reading list entries are stored in the bookmarks file, so yes (kind of).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I whipped up a Python script to read the plist file referenced in the [question patrix mentioned in the comments](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30519/devs-can-3rd-party-apps-access-safaris-reading-list).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import plistlib
from shutil import copy
import subprocess
import os
from tempfile import gettempdir
import sys
import atexit

BOOKMARKS_PLIST = '~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist'
bookmarksFile = os.path.expanduser(BOOKMARKS_PLIST)

# Make a copy of the bookmarks and convert it from a binary plist to text
tempDirectory = gettempdir()
copy(bookmarksFile, tempDirectory)
bookmarksFileCopy = os.path.join(tempDirectory, os.path.basename(bookmarksFile))

def removeTempFile():
    os.remove(bookmarksFileCopy)

atexit.register(removeTempFile) # Delete the temp file when the script finishes

converted = subprocess.call(['plutil', '-convert', 'xml1', bookmarksFileCopy])

if converted != 0:
    print "Couldn't convert bookmarks plist from xml format"
    sys.exit(converted)

plist = plistlib.readPlist(bookmarksFileCopy)
 # There should only be one Reading List item, so take the first one
readingList = [item for item in plist['Children'] if 'Title' in item and item['Title'] == 'com.apple.ReadingList'][0]

if 'Children' in readingList:
    for item in readingList['Children']:
        print item['URLString']
```

Copy and paste that into a file, name it something like `readinglisturls.py`. Then make it executable by running `chmod +x readinglisturls.py` in the Terminal. Then you can run it in the Terminal and it will print out any Reading List URLs. If you want the URLs in a file, you can redirect the output to a file by running `/path/to/readinglisturls.py > myfile.txt` in the Terminal.

Comment: This script is also available as a Gist on Github, if that’s useful to anyone: https://gist.github.com/robmathers/5995026

Answer (score 2):

Another option using the plist Ruby gem:

`sudo gem install plist;plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist|ruby -rubygems -e 'require "plist";puts Plist.parse_xml(STDIN.read)["Children"].select{|e|e["Title"]=="com.apple.ReadingList"}[0]["Children"].map{|e|e["URLString"]}'`

Or if you don't have other bookmarks:

`defaults read ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist | sed -En 's/^ *URLString = "(.*)";/\1/p'`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using the [Factor programming language](http://factorcode.org) that is a bit simpler than the Python version answered already in this post:

```
: reading-list ( -- urls )
    "~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist" read-plist
    "Children" of [ "Title" of "com.apple.ReadingList" = ] find nip
    "Children" of [ "URLString" of ] map ;
```

More information is available in this [blog post](http://re-factor.blogspot.com/2013/07/reading-list.html).